# Execute python script via Arduino Uno in windows

Tags: python, arduino-uno

I am wondering is there any way to run python script via Arduino commands in Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answers your question, but you can download Vpython library to create some cool projects with it, or connect sensors and getting data back into python from arduino or viceversa

So for example:

```
int trigPin=13; //Sensor Trig pin connected to Arduino pin 13
int echoPin=11;  //Sensor Echo pin connected to Arduino pin 11
float pingTime;  //time for ping to travel from sensor to target and return
float targetDistance; //Distance to Target in inches
float speedOfSound=776.5; //Speed of sound in miles per hour when temp is 77 degrees.

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //Set trigger pin low
  delayMicroseconds(2000); //Let signal settle
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //Set trigPin high
  delayMicroseconds(15); //Delay in high state
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //ping has now been sent
  delayMicroseconds(10); //Delay in low state

  pingTime = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);  //pingTime is presented in microceconds
  pingTime=pingTime/1000000; //convert pingTime to seconds by dividing by 1000000 (microseconds in a second)
  pingTime=pingTime/3600; //convert pingtime to hourse by dividing by 3600 (seconds in an hour)
  targetDistance= speedOfSound * pingTime;  //This will be in miles, since speed of sound was miles per hour
  targetDistance=targetDistance/2; //Remember ping travels to target and back from target, so you must divide by 2 for actual target distance.
  targetDistance= targetDistance*63360;    //Convert miles to inches by multipling by 63360 (inches per mile)

  Serial.println(targetDistance);

  delay(100); //delay tenth of a  second to slow things down a little.
}
```

And in python

```
import serial #Import Serial Library
from visual import * #Import all the vPython library

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com11', 9600) #Create an object for the Serial port. Adjust 'com11' to whatever port your arduino is sending to.
measuringRod = cylinder( radius= .1, length=6, color=color.yellow, pos=(-3,-2,0))
lengthLabel = label(pos=(0,5,0), text='Target Distance is: ', box=false, height=30)
target=box(pos=(0,-.5,0), length=.2, width=3, height=3, color=color.green)
while (1==1):  #Create a loop that continues to read and display the data
    rate(20)#Tell vpython to run this loop 20 times a second
    if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):  #Check to see if a data point is available on the serial port
        myData = arduinoSerialData.readline() #Read the distance measure as a string
        print myData #Print the measurement to confirm things are working
        distance = float(myData) #convert reading to a floating point number
        measuringRod.length=distance #Change the length of your measuring rod to your last measurement
        target.pos=(-3+distance,-.5,0)
        myLabel= 'Target Distance is: ' + myData #Create label by appending string myData to string
        lengthLabel.text = myLabel #display updated myLabel on your graphic
```

This will make graphics in python representing something you are holding in front of an ultrasonic sensor and you can see the object moving in real time

I took the code from this website:

[Toptechboy](http://www.toptechboy.com/arduino/python-with-ardiuno-3-example-using-ultrasonic-sensor/)

This is has really good tutorial how to hook up arduino to python! And is very simple

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there won't be any Arduino library that support Python because python is interpreted and the Arduino doesn't have the memory for the entire of Python, if you're looking to program an Arduino using Python then maybe just try C the code you need to learn for programming the Arduino isn't too different to the code you would find in python most of the code you can find here : 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

but these are some of the python modules related to running Python on an Arduino : http://playground.arduino.cc/CommonTopics/PyMite